# How we can change form design by URL id using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

### 1st url for help

https://www.kijiji.ca/p-select-category.html

### 2nd url for help

https://www.kijiji.ca/p-post-ad.html?categoryId=12
[image]

### 3rd url for help

https://www.kijiji.ca/p-post-ad.html?categoryId=174
[image]

Comment: You can retrieve value from query string. Do display conditional views as per the value of `categoryId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on condition you have to change the view.

Condition in the id you get from url.

```
$id = $_GET['categoryId'];
```

`$id` will have the id from url.

Now for view(disign)

```
if($id == 174) {
     // display the view.
}
```